# Can't install memcached 1.4.5 as a service on Windows

Tags: windows, service, memcached

Last night someone told me about memcached. It seems something I can really use to reduce loading times. So today I wanted to download the latest version 1.4.5 for Windows. I found a precompiled version and wanted to use that. However as of version 1.4.5 the `-d` parameter for Windows has been dropped? And I can't install it as a service.

I tried to install it via SC, and that worked, but then when i tried to start it there came an error message that:

> The service is not responding to the control function.

I don't really know what to do now. Can I still use this on Windows as a non-service, or should I get the much older version 1.2.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this thread for you, it may help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/a185e766-41f5-402c-8519-48242d478d00

Answer (score 0):

I have used ServiceEx to install as a service.

http://serviceex.com/

Here is what I did:

1. Copied ServiceEx.exe to the Memcached directory
2. Created Memcached.ini and configured it (http://serviceex.com/files/ServiceEx.ini.sample)
3. Run command Line

> ServiceEx install Memcached

Answer (score 0):

According to the information on this page:

[Installing Memcached on Windows](https://commaster.net/content/installing-memcached-windows)

version 1.4.5 or later can not be installed as a service. It must be installed as a Windows task. Instructions to do that (for all users), considering two instances of the application:

**CREATE MEMCACHED TASKS**

```
SCHTASKS /create /sc onstart /ru system /tn memcached1 /tr "C:\Xampp\memcached\memcached.exe -m80 -p11211"
SCHTASKS /create /sc onstart /ru system /tn memcached2 /tr "C:\Xampp\memcached\memcached.exe -m80 -p11212"
```

The tasks above will run automatically on restart. However, if you want to run them immediately after their creation, do as follows:

```
SCHTASKS /run /tn memcached1
SCHTASKS /run /tn memcached2
```

To stop the tasks:

```
SCHTASKS /end /tn memcached1
SCHTASKS /end /tn memcached2
```

To delete the tasks created, execute the commands below:

**DELETE MEMCACHED TASKS**

```
SCHTASKS /delete /tn memcached1 /f
SCHTASKS /delete /tn memcached2 /f
```